# Spring Boot - package application classes as a jar in BOOT-INF/lib

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1 with Gradle 3.1. The module which has the Spring Boot plugin applied creates its own jar with the `jar` task, and also has the 'fat' jar created with `bootRepackage`. However, the classes from that module are in BOOT-INF/classes, but I would like them to be in a separate jar in BOOT-INF/lib. How to do this?

**EDIT:** I know I can move the code to a separate module, but for various reasons I can't make such a split (unless there is no other way). I am looking for a single-module solution, if one exists.

Comment: Why don't you want the classes to be in `BOOT-INF/classes`?

Comment: Because of this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#jersey-classpath-scanning-limitations. The suggested workaround is to package the application classes as a jar, have them unpacked from the fat jar and then Jersey scanning will work again.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up a [multi-project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) and  move all of your Jersey-related classes into a separate project. You can then depend upon this new project in your Spring Boot project using a `project` dependency. For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':jersey-endpoints')
}
```

Comment: Yup, I know about this way but was kind of hoping there were an easier way, especially since the documentation suggests doing this. What was the reason for introducing such a breaking change for many (at least I know of quite a few fellow projects having the issue)? Does the new layout actually have advantages warranting the change?

Comment: If you already know of one approach that answers your question, then it would have been nice to say so in your question. What a waste of time.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I updated the question. Still, it would be nice for the documentation to mention what the approaches are, it would save even more time.